# Rails - operations on multiple attributes of the same record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-programming

Given a `Review` model and a `reviews` table defined as follow:

```
 id | avg_rating | reviews_count
---------------------------------
  1 |          4 |            12
  2 |          5 |             2
  3 |          1 |             9
  4 |          3 |             1
```

I need to calculate a weighted_rating; currently I do:

```
sum = 0

Review.all.each do |review|
  sum = sum + review.avg_rating * review.reviews_count
end

weighted_rating = sum / Review.sum(:reviews_count)
```

Is there a cooler & functional way to get this done in Rails?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888051/rails-3-sum-product-of-two-fields this may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the appraoch by @Sujay:

```
Review.sum("avg_rating * reviews_count") / Review.sum(:reviews_count)
```

Comment: I think this will fire two queries, right? Since I have a large `reviews` table I finally ended up loading the collection in memory (`.to_a`) and working on it as an Array

Comment: @davideghz `Review.sum("avg_rating * reviews_count / SUM(reviews_count)")` should work as well - the more you can do in SQL on the db the better. loading everything into memory is performance-wise the worst solution.